# How to loop in powershell where loop value is combination of string and variable

Tags: powershell

```
$A1= get-content -path  "File path a1"
$B1= get-content -path "File path b1"
$A2= get-content -path "File path a2"
$B2= get-content -path "File path B2"
$A3= get-content -path "File path a3"
$B3= get-content -path "File path B3"

#I want to select A.i and B.i in each loop

while ($i -le 5)
{
foreach ($line1 in "What to put here"))
{
$found = $false
foreach ($line2 in "What to put here"))
{
if ($line1 -eq $line2)
{
   write-host "Do something"
}
}
```

I want to know what should I use in "what to put here" so that 
a) first loop select a1 and b1 files
b) second loop selects a2 and b2 files
and so on

---

Hello,
The below code is taking too long for large files to print whats different in each file. Can you suggest some optimization?

```
$i = 1
while ($i -le 7)
{
$t1 = Get-Content -Path $(($oldpath) +($(Get-Variable "F$i").Value) +($Format))
$t2 = Get-Content -Path $(($NEWpath) +($(Get-Variable "F$i").Value) +($Format))
$list1      = new-object 'system.collections.generic.list[string]'
$list2      = new-object 'system.collections.generic.list[string]'
$listshared = new-object 'system.collections.generic.list[string]'
$found = $false

foreach ($line1 in $t1)
{
$found = $false
foreach ($line2 in $t2)
if (-not $found) 
{
   $list1.add($line1)
}
}

foreach ($line2 in $t2)
{
$found = $false
foreach ($line1 in $t1)

if (-not $found)
{
   $list2.add($line2)
}
}
Write-Host "Things only in new txt file:" -foreground "magenta"
$list1

Write-Host "Things only in old txt file:" -foreground "magenta"
$list2

Remove-Variable "t1"
Remove-Variable "t2"
$i++
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example:

```
Get-Variable -Name "A$i" |select Value
```

but it seems like a bad practice to use a variable for each file...
But you did not specify if you compare paths or files.
If files, combine with `Get-Content`.

UPDATE:

```
$i=1
while ($i -le 5)
{
$file1=Get-Content -Path $($(Get-Variable "A$i").Value)
$file2=Get-Content -Path $($(Get-Variable "B$i").Value)
    foreach ($line1 in $file1)
    {
        $found = $false
        foreach ($line2 in $file2)
        {
            if ($line1 -eq $line2)
            {
                write-host "Do something"
            }
        }

    }
    Remove-Variable "file1"
    Remove-Variable "file2"
    $i++
}
```

This is the version without `Get-Content` at every variable

Comment: I have updated the variables definition as in my post. I am comparing files in the defined variable location . When i am using Get-variable its not working out. I have used as following: foreach ($line1 in (Get-variable -Name "A$i" |select Value)) . Since am not an expert, please excuse my naive query. –  Santosh Pillai 15 mins ago

Comment: @SantoshPillai Are you aware that in your code you did not initialize $i and you are not incrementing it?

Comment: Sorry i didn't paste the entire code.$i will be incremented thru numbers..I have put i++ in code

Comment: @SantoshPillai Ok, I improved the answer to fit your code

Comment: Hello @Deptor,the code is working fine but taking a long for large files to print the difference in each file. i have added the new code in my question. Please check if you can suggest something?

Comment: @SantoshPillai Can you tell how big the files are? above 5MB? above 500MB? Maybe the approach should be changed. Do you store lines only to display them?

Comment: Files are just 180 kb with just 10,000 lines.. it takes aroun 3 min to find the difference in each file..In linux shell, using diff command it doesn't even take a sec ..do we have any such command in powershell

Comment: @SantoshPillai Try in this case compare-object $t1 $t2. Use get-help to see the optional parameters.

Comment: Yes @Deptor. It doesnt give as detailed in previous code but still helps. Thanks